# Sorting NewID() weird result on MS SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

all I just found something which looks weird for me, or probably I don't get nature of those NewID() values,  I clearly see that order is wrong, for both Asc and Desc, can you help me to test in on other env /

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('NXTest', 'Collation')  ----SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

; WITH cte AS ( SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '1' RecID,  NewID() ID UNION  SELECT '2' RecID,  NewID() ID UNION  SELECT '3' RecID,  NewID() ID UNION
SELECT '4' RecID,  NewID() ID UNION  SELECT '5' RecID,  NewID() ID UNION  SELECT '6' RecID,  NewID() ID )b )
SELECT * INTO #t FROM cte

SELECT *, LEN(iD) FROM #t   order BY ID     DESC
```

Those are my IDs, for true test too:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '1' RecID,  'B299ADAD-6A0C-4904-B04A-699714594175' ID UNION  SELECT '2' RecID,  '6CA58D90-CEDF-49E7-8C39-731A2B3F2387' ID UNION  
SELECT '3' RecID,  'F3CBCA7E-5F6E-42F5-B7E1-9DEF050239F6' ID UNION SELECT '4' RecID,  'FD22EAD9-094C-4F50-98D0-3A5D4EE0A500' ID UNION  
SELECT '5' RecID,  '9E3BFE14-701E-419E-B830-AD8717D9FA58' ID UNION  SELECT '6' RecID,  'AA35A5EC-0D09-43C8-B7CE-EB5948DD05A7' ID )b
```

Results are clearly wrong for me, mix of 9s and As, appreciate if you can help me.
[image: This are my results:]

Comment: I dun understand. What do you expect? NEWID is just for generating a unique key... sorting NEWID is some kind of meaningless...The displayed value is not the real value, take a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you want sort based values you can also use NEWSEQUENTIALID - But this can only be used as a default column. This means it would be a value set when you insert data. More reading here: https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/martinbell/archive/2009/05/25/GUID-Ordering-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: Solved !!!  , there is a special data type UniqueID, after casting to varhar  it works OK as expected Tx all

Answer (score 2):

When you insert **`NEWID()`** value to a table, the datatype is **`uniqueidentifier`**. So you have to cast it to **`varchar`**. That's the reason the sorting is not giving properly.

```
;with cte as ( 
    select * from (
        select '1' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] union
        select '2' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] union
        select '3' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] union
        select '4' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] union
        select '5' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] union
        select '6' as [RecID],  cast(NewID() as varchar(36)) [ID] 
    ) b 
)
select * into #t 
from cte;

select *, len([ID]) from #t 
order by [ID] desc;
```